# Can't configure network on ubuntu server using drac

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I have installed Ubuntu 14 server on my server using DRAC of Dell. I have got all the info from my server company like IP Addresses, Gateway, Netmask and so on. I have tried to configure the network using DHCP. I have tried static IP with the details I have. But no matter what I do, I can't seem to make it work. When I'm trying to ping 8.8.8.8 I get `connect: Network is unreachable`

Thanks

Comment: Pls post the output of these 5 commands: *cat /etc/network/interfaces*,  *ip link show*, *ip route show*, *ip addr show*, *sudo service network-manager status*.

Comment: Thanks marius
cat /etc/network/interfaces brings: http://pastebin.com/ccByMhhR
ip link show bring: http://pastebin.com/kSqgPrUH
ip route show brings: `72.5.232.0/22 dev em1 proto kernel scope link src 72.5.234.152`
ip addr show brings: http://pastebin.com/V8m1xPfc
service network-manager status brings: `network-manager: unrecognized service`

Comment: The output of /etc/network/interfaces seems to me disturbingly wrong. Could I pls ask you to double check with  your company that these numbers are right? I find it incredible that you should be given as static IP address a Dynamic IP used by ATT in California, and then that you should use as gateway the public, routable IP of a North Carolina college. It does not make any sense.

Comment: thanks @MariusMatutiae 
please check the updated pastebin: http://pastebin.com/u22rAAkX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new version of your /etc/network/interfaces file

```
     auto lo
     iface lo inet loopback

     auto em1
     iface em1 inet static
     address 72.3.234.152
     netmask 255.255.252.0
     network 172.30.0.152
     broadcast 172.30.0.255
     dns-nameservers 172.30.0.1 8.8.8.8
     gateway 172.30.0.1
```

at least look less disastrously wrong than the previous, but it is still wrong. Still there are some problems which you will have to sort out with your IT people:

1. 172.30.0.152 is **not** a network. A network ends in *0* (zero), so it might (?) be 172.30.0.0 instead.
2. 172.30.0.255 is **not** the broadcast of 172.30.0.0 netmask 255.255.252.0: 172.30.3.255 **is**.
3. your address is **not** a member of network: in fact 72.3.23.152 is not included between 172.30.0.1 and 172.30.3.25, as it should.

Please make sure you verify these details with your IT people. Also, I hope that this configuration is for your server *inside* your work place network, not at home. If you are setting up your home network, none of this makes any sense.

EDIT:

should I remark that this is the third different configuration that your IT guys give you? At any rate, **if** these are the correct data, then your /etc/networking/interfaces file should look like this:

```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto em1
   iface em1 inet static
   address 72.3.234.152
   netmask 255.255.255.248
   network 72.3.234.152
   broadcast 72.3.234.159
   dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
   gateway 72.3.234.153
```

These numbers still appear suspicious to me, because 72.3.234.152 is a network: in fact, your network is 72.3.234.152/29, and the first and last addresses of the network (72.3.234.152 and 72.3.234.159) are *reserved* addresses. But, in any case, this is all that can be done with the info you are given. Reboot, and keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: thanks marius. 
it is a server, not in my home. in a big company server farm. i'll speak with the IT people and let you know. thanks.
by the way i host it on rackspace. they are pretty big company and i dont think they put my ip to be not included between the range you said . but i asked them anyway.

Comment: after a checking with my IT people i just logged in in the control panel of my server and i found it really deep somewhere the following details:
http://pastebin.com/mZpis8Rk
and now when i ping 8.8.8.8 i get 
From 72.3.234.152 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: @Benny Pls see my edit.

Comment: you were right. the problem was with the ip address they provided me. thank you for your help.